# ANDROID - Send a screenshot from java to android via tcp socket

Tags: java, android, image, sockets, tcp

I made a Client-Server chat via sockets and it works great. Now I want to include an option for the server(Android phone) to grap a screenshot from the client(pc application). Creating the screenshot works fine, but the transfer from the client to the server fails every time.

**CLIENT-SIDE / SENDER:**

Before I wrote the image directly to an output stream, but I get an error on the server side and so I tried this way, but it's just the same.

```
public class ClientScreenshotThread implements Runnable {

// - Software Init - //
private Socket transferSocket;
private BufferedImage screenshot;
private Robot robot;
private BufferedWriter outToServer;
private FileInputStream inStream;
private DataOutputStream outStream;

// - Var Init - //
private final int SERVER_TRANSFER_PORT = 65000;

private int screenWidth, screenHeight;

// -------------------------------------------------- //

public ClientScreenshotThread() {

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(Client.SERVER_IP, SERVER_TRANSFER_PORT);
        transferSocket = new Socket();
        transferSocket.connect(sockaddr, 5000);     // 5sec Timeout

        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        robot = new Robot();

        screenWidth = dimension.width;
        screenHeight = dimension.height;

        Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(screenWidth, screenHeight);

        screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(screen);
        ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", new File("/Users/chris/Downloads/screenshot.png"));

        File file = new File("/Users/chris/Downloads/screenshot.png");
        inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        // prepare server for receiving the screenshot
        outToServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(transferSocket.getOutputStream()));
        outToServer.write("#!<cmd>screenshot");
        outToServer.newLine();
        outToServer.flush();

        // send the screenshot to the server
        outStream = new DataOutputStream(transferSocket.getOutputStream());

        int n;
        int i = 0;
        while((n = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i + ". Byte[" + n + "]");
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
            outStream.flush();
        }

    } catch(AWTException e1) {
        System.out.println("AWT: " + e1.getMessage().toString());
    } catch(IOException e2) {
        System.out.println("IO: " + e2.getMessage().toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            // close streams and socket
            inStream.close();
            outToServer.close();
            transferSocket.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

**SERVER-SIDE / RECEIVER:**

I always get a "NullPointerException" at:

**bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutStream);**

```
public class ServerTransferThread implements Runnable {

// - Software Init - //
private ServerSocket serverTransferSocket;
private Handler handler;
private BufferedReader inFromClient;
private DataInputStream inStream;
private ByteArrayOutputStream content;
private FileOutputStream fileOutStream;

// - Var Init - //
private final String TAG = "xxx";

private final int SERVER_TRANSFER_PORT = 65000;

// -------------------------------------------------- //

public ServerTransferThread(Handler _handler) {
    this.handler = _handler;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ServerTransferThread: run()");

    try {
        serverTransferSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_TRANSFER_PORT);

        while(ServerActivity.SERVER_STATE == true) {
            Socket socket = serverTransferSocket.accept();
            Log.d(TAG, "ServerTransferThread: accepted()");

            inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            Log.d(TAG, "ServerTransferThread: bufferedReader()");

            String message = "";
            if((message = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {
                if(message.equals("#!<cmd>screenshot")) {
                    receiveScreenshot(socket);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ServerTransferThread 1: " + e.getMessage().toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            inFromClient.close();
            serverTransferSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ServerTransferThread 2: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }
}

private void receiveScreenshot(Socket socketX) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ServerTransferThread: receiveScreenshot()");

    try {
        handler.sendMessage(buildMessage("> Receiving screenshot.."));
        inStream = new DataInputStream(socketX.getInputStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        inStream = new DataInputStream(socketX.getInputStream());

        int n;
        while((n = inStream.read()) != -1) {     
            content.write(buffer, 0, n);     // HERE I "OUT OF MEMORY"
            content.flush();
        }

        File directory = new File(ServerActivity.APP_FOLDER_PATH);
        File screenshot = new File(ServerActivity.APP_FOLDER_PATH + "/" + "screenshot.png");

        if(!directory.exists())
            directory.mkdirs();

        if(!screenshot.exists()) {
            screenshot.createNewFile();
        }
        else {
            screenshot.delete();
            screenshot.createNewFile();
        }

        fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(screenshot);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(content.toByteArray(), 0, content.size());
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutStream);

        handler.sendMessage(buildMessage("> Screenshot received sucessfully!"));

    } catch(IOException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ServerTransferThread 3: " + e1.getMessage().toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            inStream.close();
            content.close();
            fileOutStream.close();
            socketX.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ServerTransferThread 4: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    }
}

private Message buildMessage(String text) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ServerTransferThread: buildMessage()");

    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("MESSAGE", text);
    msg.setData(bundle);
    return msg;
}
```

**Here is my Logcat output:**

```
08-20 19:01:18.285: D/skia(5383): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-20 19:01:18.295: W/dalvikvm(5383): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c6b1f8)
08-20 19:01:18.295: E/AndroidRuntime(5383): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3051
08-20 19:01:18.295: E/AndroidRuntime(5383): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 19:01:18.295: E/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at net.api.speak.wifi.ServerTransferThread.receiveScreenshot(ServerTransferThread.java:114)
08-20 19:01:18.295: E/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at net.api.speak.wifi.ServerTransferThread.run(ServerTransferThread.java:58)
08-20 19:01:18.295: E/AndroidRuntime(5383):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-20 19:01:27.820: D/Speak WiFi(5383): Server: onDestroy()
08-20 19:01:27.830: E/Speak WiFi(5383): Server: Socket closed
08-20 19:01:27.830: E/Speak WiFi(5383): ServerThread: Socket closed
```

---

**EDIT:** After some troubles I've found a final solution for the file transfer problem! There it is:

---

**Final Server side:**

```
            int bytecount = 2048;
            byte[] buf = new byte[bytecount];

            OutputStream OUT = socket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream BuffOUT = new BufferedOutputStream(OUT, bytecount);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(itemPath);

            int i = 0;
            while ((i = in.read(buf, 0, bytecount)) != -1) {
                BuffOUT.write(buf, 0, i);
                BuffOUT.flush();
            }
```

**Final Client side:**

```
        FileOutputStream outToFile = new FileOutputStream(FileName);

        int bytecount = 2048;
        byte[] buf = new byte[bytecount];

        // Create an inputstream for the file data to arrive
        InputStream IN = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream BuffIN = new BufferedInputStream(IN, bytecount);

        // Receiving file..
        int i = 0;
        int filelength = 0;       
        while((i = BuffIN.read(buf, 0, bytecount)) != -1) {
            filelength += i;
            outToFile.write(buf, 0, i);
            outToFile.flush();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you write the received bytes directly to a FileOutputStream.
Converting the png to a bitmap on a rather limited device like a smartphone will cause problems sometimes.

Do you need to create the Bitmap object on the receiver side?

If not, you can do something like this:

```
InputStream is = socketX.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(screenshot);

int n;
while ((n = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
  outputFile.write(data, 0, n);
}
```

I haven't tested the code.

Comment: No, I don't need to convert the Bitmap on the receiver side. So you mean I should handle this with an ObjectOutputStream? Can you explain that a bit? I read lots of topic from google, but nothing solves my problem :/

Comment: It works to write the input data to a file (don't know if the data is correct) - but thats just a file.png.. I have to convert this file to a image format, but how? I tried with BitmapFactory.decodeFile("path/to/screenshot") - thats throws a nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException is because the `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` returns: The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decode.

Server-side (inside receiveScreenshot() method), the part that writes the InputStream bytes into the ByteArrayOutputStream 'content' variable is not correct, because `inStream.read()` should be `inStream.read(buffer)`

The Out of Memory error can be explained because `read()` method only reads one byte at a time, and then for each byte you always write a full buffer of 4096 bytes.

**Edit:** To compress OutputStream to png once you have written all the bytes inside the fileOutputStream and when you don't want to directly provide the bytes (because in your case it is what didn't work):

```
// Write bytes inside fileOutStream

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(screenshot.getAbsolutePath());
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutStream);
fileOutStream.close();
```

This should work for your needs, but it's a pity to decode the file since you should already know the bytes inside..

Comment: thanks, I think I forgot that. But it didn't solve the problem. The nullpointerexception still occurs because I receive real bullshit. The sender and the receiver side display now how much byte[] and with which size they send/receive and I noticed that the bytes I send out don't match the byte[] I receive at all.

Comment: I send out 87 byte[] - 86 with the size [4096] and the 87. with [771] but I receive 214 byte[] - the first 3 are okay but then it starts getting crazy.. lengths of [1448] to [3352].. wtf -- the last byte[] (the 214. oô) is correct -> [771].

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem. I tested your code and it works fine for me (one client sending image from sdcard). Even if you read smaller chunks, does the total bytes you receive match the total bytes you send ?