# Sending Image from Java server to android client

Tags: java, android, image, screenshot, tcpsocket

I am wrting a remote desktop application, for that I need to send screenshot from desktop to android phone. The screenshot is getting created and I guess also able to write on the DataOutputstrean, but on the client side it fails to read properly. Here are the codes:

### Server.java :

```
    import java.awt.AWTException;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

public class Main {

```
private static BufferedImage screenshot;
private static Robot robot;
private static BufferedWriter outToClient;
private static FileInputStream inStream;
private static DataOutputStream outStream;
private static int screenWidth;
private static int screenHeight;
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String message;
private static Thread screenThread;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(21112);  //Server socket

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 21111");
    }

    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 21111");

    while (true) {
        try {

            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();   //accept the client connection
            System.out.println("accepted");
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);

            Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            robot = new Robot();
            System.out.println("After robot object in thread");
            screenWidth = dimension.width;
            screenHeight = dimension.height;

            Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(screenWidth, screenHeight);

            screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(screen);
            File file = new File("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/screenshot.png");

            ImageIO.write(screenshot, "jpeg", file);
            System.out.println("After ImageIO.write");

            inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            System.out.println("After Fileinstram");
            // prepare client for receiving the screenshot
            outToClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
            outToClient.write("#!<cmd>screenshot");
            System.out.println("After preparing client to read the image file");
            outToClient.newLine();
            outToClient.flush();

            // send the screenshot to the client
            outStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("After Datastream output obj");
            int n;
            int i = 0;

            while((n = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                System.out.println("In while");
                i++;
                System.out.println(i + ". Byte[" + n + "]");
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
                outStream.flush();

            }

        } catch(AWTException e1) {
            System.out.println("AWT: " + e1.getMessage().toString());
        } catch(IOException e2) {
            System.out.println("IO: " + e2.getMessage().toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                // close streams and socket
                inStream.close();
                outToClient.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }


            //inputStreamReader.close();
           // clientSocket.close();


    }

}
```

}

### Client.java (Android client):

```
package roman10.tutorial.tcpcommclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class TcpClient extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static Socket s;
    private Handler handler;
    private BufferedReader inFromServer;
    private DataInputStream inStream;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream content;
    private FileOutputStream fileOutStream;
    private final String TAG = "xxx";

private final int SERVER_TRANSFER_PORT = 21115;
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.e("TcpClient" , "in creaste");
    runTcpClient();
   // finish();
}

private static final int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 21115;
private void runTcpClient() {
    try {
         while( true) {
             s = new Socket("10.4.9.169", TCP_SERVER_PORT);
            Log.e("TcpClient" , "socket created");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            //send output msg

            String outMsg = "TCP connectingfghg to " + System.getProperty("line.separator") ; 
            out.write(outMsg);
            out.flush();
            Log.e("TcpClient", "sent: " + outMsg);

            inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            Log.d(TAG, "ServerTransferThread: bufferedReader()");

            String message = "";
            if((message = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
                if(message.equals("#!<cmd>screenshot")) {
                    receiveScreenshot(s);
                }
            }
         }
        /*
        Thread cclientscreen = new Thread(new ClientTransferThread(new Handler()));
        cclientscreen.start();*/
        //accept server response
        //String inMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        //Log.e("TcpClient", "received: " + inMsg);
        //close connection

    }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ClientTransferThread 1: " + e.getMessage().toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            inFromServer.close();
            //s.close();
            //serverTransferSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ClientTransferThread 2: " + e.getMessage().toString());
        }
    } 
}

 public static Socket getS() {
        return s;
      }

      public static void setS(Socket s) {
        TcpClient.s = s;
    }
    private void receiveScreenshot(Socket socketX) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ClientTransferThread: receiveScreenshot()");

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "receiveScreenshot(): receiving screenshot");
           // handler.sendMessage(buildMessage("> Receiving screenshot.."));
            inStream = new DataInputStream(socketX.getInputStream());

            Log.d(TAG, "receiveScreenshot(): after datastream");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int n;
            while((n = inStream.read()) != -1) { 

                content.write(buffer, 0, n); 
                Log.d(TAG, "rcvscrnshot: in while");// HERE I "OUT OF MEMORY"
                content.flush();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "rcvscrnshot: outside while");
           // File directory = new File(ServerActivity.APP_FOLDER_PATH);
            //File screenshot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState()  + "/" + "screenshot.png");
            String path = "/storage/sdcard/picshello";
            File outputDir= new File(path); 

            Log.d(TAG, "rcvscrnshot: after outfilepath dir");

            outputDir.mkdirs();
            Log.d(TAG, "rcvscrnshot: mkdir");
            File screenshot = new File(path+"/"+"screenshot.jpeg");
            Log.d(TAG, "rcvscrnshot: opening png file");
           // FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(screenshot);   
            //bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);   
//          if(!directory.exists())
//              directory.mkdirs();
/*
            if(!screenshot.exists()) {
                screenshot.createNewFile();
            }
            else {
                screenshot.delete();
                screenshot.createNewFile();
            }
*/
            Log.d(TAG, "rcvscrnshot: file created");
            fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(screenshot);
            Log.d(TAG, "rcvscrnshot: fileoutstream");
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(content.toByteArray(), 0, content.size());
            Log.d(TAG, "rcvscrnshot: bmp created");
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutStream);
            Log.d(TAG, "rcvscrnshot: bmp compressed");

            //handler.sendMessage(buildMessage("> Screenshot received sucessfully!"));

        } catch(IOException e1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ClientTransferThread 3: " + e1.getMessage().toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                inStream.close();
                content.close();
                fileOutStream.close();
                socketX.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ClientTransferThread 4: " + e.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private Message buildMessage(String text) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ClientTransferThread: buildMessage()");

        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("MESSAGE", text);
        msg.setData(bundle);
        return msg;
    }
    /*
    //replace runTcpClient() at onCreate with this method if you want to run tcp client as a    service
    private void runTcpClientAsService() {
        Intent lIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), TcpClientService.class);
        this.startService(lIntent);
    }
    */
}
```

### Logcat(client):

```
... // After creating socket it prints "in while" many times
11-03 00:11:05.373: D/xxx(7134): rcvscrnshot: in while
11-03 00:11:05.373: D/xxx(7134): rcvscrnshot: in while
11-03 00:11:05.373: D/xxx(7134): rcvscrnshot: outside while
11-03 00:11:05.373: D/xxx(7134): rcvscrnshot: after outfilepath dir
11-03 00:11:05.373: D/xxx(7134): rcvscrnshot: mkdir
11-03 00:11:05.373: D/xxx(7134): rcvscrnshot: opening jpeg file
11-03 00:11:05.373: D/xxx(7134): rcvscrnshot: file created
11-03 00:11:05.373: D/xxx(7134): rcvscrnshot: fileoutstream
11-03 00:11:05.453: D/dalvikvm(7134): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 825K, 43% free 11154K/19452K, paused 80ms, total 80ms
11-03 00:11:05.573: I/dalvikvm-heap(7134): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.806MB for 8222931-byte allocation
11-03 00:11:05.673: D/dalvikvm(7134): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 31% free 19185K/27484K, paused 80ms, total 80ms
11-03 00:11:05.693: D/skia(7134): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
11-03 00:11:05.693: D/xxx(7134): rcvscrnshot: bmp created
11-03 00:11:05.713: D/AndroidRuntime(7134): Shutting down VM
11-03 00:11:05.713: W/dalvikvm(7134): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a99ba8)
11-03 00:11:05.733: E/AndroidRuntime(7134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 00:11:05.733: E/AndroidRuntime(7134): Process: roman10.tutorial.tcpcommclient, PID: 7134
11-03 00:11:05.733: E/AndroidRuntime(7134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{roman10.tutorial.tcpcommclient/roman10.tutorial.tcpcommclient.TcpClient}: 
                    java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 00:11:05.733: E/AndroidRuntime(7134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
11-03 00:11:05.733: E/AndroidRuntime(7134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
```

Console(Server):

```
Server started. Listening to the port 21111
accepted
TCP connectingfghg to 
After robot object in thread
After ImageIO.write
After Fileinstram
After preparing client to read the image file
After Datastream output obj
In while
1. Byte[4096]
In while
..... // Like this till it reads the whole file.
```

I am stuck on this for 2 days, tried this code from stackoverflow(link: [ANDROID - Send a screenshot from java to android via tcp socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041986/android-send-a-screenshot-from-java-to-android-via-tcp-socket)) 
I also get the same error but answer mentioned is not working or I am implementing it wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of design errors:

Don't use both a `BufferedWriter` and a `DataOutputStream` to send/receive data through the socket, if you want to send a string you can use the `DataOutpurStream` `writeUTF(aString)` method.

Execute the reading (from the socket) on another thread because this code `while((n = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1)` will block until the socket is close.

In the client code you are running the socket communication on the UI Thread which will block your application, create another thread for that.

You run out of memory because you're using:

```
 while((n = inStream.read()) != -1) { 

            content.write(buffer, 0, n); 
            ...
 }
```

Which reads only one byte from the stream and writes 4096 to the file. Instead of `read()` use `read(buffer)`

Comment: Now the image is getting send to the other end, but the problem is to convert an image to Bitmap type on the sender side before sending.. Do we need to convert in byte array in Bitmap before sending so as to decode it into image on client side? Can you please tell me how to we convert byte array to bitmap in java?

Comment: In the server's code change `ImageIO.write(screenshot, "jpeg", file);` to `ImageIO.write(screenshot, "BMP", file);`

Comment: Still Im getting the same error:  D/xxx(27091): in while current:3148854
11-03 02:10:27.793: D/skia(27091): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null                                                         what changes should be done in reciever(android client)?

Comment: @user2621826 : Make sure you get the entire image by checking its size before you send it and after you receive it.

Comment: I checked, the size is equal to the size on the laptop, what else can be the problem, its still giving the above problem